# Best Practices for Seperating jQuery from HTML/PHP

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, customization

I am creating several jQuery scripts to help validate forms before they are submitted.  I have read that it is best to always separate jQuery scripts into a separate file so that you can load the script with [`wp_enqeue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

However, if I am doing something like this:

```
jQuery(function()
{
    var ButtonSelector = "#submit-button";

    jQuery(document).on('click', ButtonSelector, function()
    {
        var ValidEntry = true;

        ClearError('#venue_name');
        var name = jQuery("#venue_name").val();
        if (name == "")
        {
            CreateError("#venue_name", "Name is Required");
            ValidEntry = false;
        }

        if (!ValidEntry)
        {
            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        }

        EnableButton(ButtonSelector);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Since this function is only used in the one individual form, would it still make sense to separate it out?  If I did separate it, wouldn't that mean that it would load for every single page?

Comment: All browsers use a cache for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can target a specific page using [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) when you are enqueueing your JS file.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    if( is_page('your page title') ){
      wp_enqueue_script( 'your-js-script' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

This way, you will conditionally [enqueue your JS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to [that page only](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page).

Answer (score 1):

you could still put the script in a seperate js-file, but separate from the rest of your script(-files) too - and enqueue it conditionally, for example:

```
if (is_page_template('abc-xyz.php')) {
    wp_enqueue_script('your_script-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/your_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.00', true);
}
```

that would be in your `functions.php`, where you enqueue your scripts

Answer (score 0):

When using `is_page()` I would also recommend doing so with an `||` since the page title and page name (aka page slug) might change - if only by accident. You could also use the page ID but that too might not be consistent between development and production.

For example:

```
if ( is_page( $name ) || is_page( $id ) || is_page( $title ) ) {}
```

Overkill? Perhaps. But it's something to be aware of.